# Criterion for convergence of sums for non-continuous functions

Tags: lie-groups, haar-measure, equidistribution

The following question came up when thinking about equidistribution of Satake parameters of elliptic curves. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Haar measure $\mathrm{d} x$. Recall that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points in $G$ is equidistributed if for all $f\in C(G)$, we have equality:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n) = \int_G f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x .
$$
Here, we fix the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and vary $f\in C(G)$. My question is based on what happens when we fix $f$ and vary the $\{x_n\}$. More precisely:

> Let $f\in L^1(G)$. Call $f$ *equidistribution-good* if the equality above holds for all equidistributed $\{x_n\}$, even though $f$ is not necessarily continuous. Is there a good analytic condition (weaker than continuity) such that if $f$ satisfies this condition, then $f$ is equidistribution-good?

If $G=S^1$, then bounded variation works, though it's not clear to me that $f$ is equidistribution-good if and only if it has bounded variation (I think bounded + a.e.-continuity is iff here).

Any partial answers or pointers to references would be super helpful!

Even better, it would be awesome if there was a good analytic criterion for which functions $f$ aren't just equidistribution-good, but satisfy 
$$
\left|\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n) - \int_G f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \right| = O_{\{x_n\},f}(\text{some kind of ``discrepancy''}) .
$$

[EDIT: I've modified the question to reflect Christian's comments.]

Comment: I think you mean "weaker than continuity" (not stronger). Also, continuity a.e. (on $S^1$) is certainly not enough, an e-g $f\in L^1$ must be bounded.

Comment: $f$ bounded and a.e. continuous sounds like it could be the right condition.

Comment: Thanks Christian - I'll see if I can prove it for bounded + a.e. continuous.

Comment: Christian—your answer is correct. If you make it into an official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh, thanks, but I was just guessing, didn't have any profound thoughts. You could just write it up yourself if you have a proof.

Comment: a.e. continuous (+bounded obviously) = Riemann integrable, by Lebesgue's theorem. One may argue whether Riemann integrable is better than $C_{c}$ or not, but in many practical cases, $C_{c}$ is enough, as you can approximate any simple function (of finitely many values, not countably many as in general measure theory) with $C_{c}$ functions to arbitrary precision.

Comment: Usually the answer to your second question is by Sobolev spaces (for that purpose, think about Sobolev space as "decay condition on Fourier coefficients"). If so, just verify the quantitative equidistribution to characters (which is usually tractable by estimating the exponential sums) and then pair it up with the decay of the full Fourier expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper "λ-equidistributed sequences of partitions and a theorem of the De Bruijn–Post type", by Chersi and Volčič, proves that if $(X,d,\lambda)$ is a separable metric space with probability measure whose support is $X$, then "$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n\leqslant N} f(x_n)\to \lambda(f)$ for all $\lambda$-equidistributed $\{x_n\}$" if and only if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.